# Why is Laravel showing sending me to the incorrect route?

Tags: laravel

I have the following routes defined for my store entity, however, whenever I visit the /stores/ page (store.list.get) I get an error for the store.edit.get route (because the id is not provided). I'm being incorrectly routed - What could be causing this issue?

```
// store
Route::get('stores', 'App\Http\Controllers\StoreController@showList')
    ->name('store.list.get')
    ->middleware('auth');

Route::get('stores/create', 'App\Http\Controllers\StoreController@showCreate')
    ->name('store.create.get')
    ->middleware('auth');

Route::post('stores/create', 'App\Http\Controllers\StoreController@create')
    ->name('store.create.post')
    ->middleware('auth');

Route::get('stores/edit/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\StoreController@showEdit')
    ->name('store.edit.get')
    ->middleware('auth')
    ->where(['id' => '^[0-9]+$']);
```

EDIT: Error message

```
Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException
Missing required parameter for [Route: store.edit.get] [URI: stores/edit/{id}] [Missing parameter: id]. (View: C:\Users\owenh\Desktop\Repositories\enderpay\admin_panel\src\resources\views\pages\store\index.blade.php)
http://127.0.0.1:8000/stores
```

Comment: Please post an error message.

Comment: Added @PrashantDeshmukh.....

Comment: How are you trying to visit that route from browser,please post that url as well.

Comment: Looks like you are not passing `{id}` parameter with url.

Comment: @PrashantDeshmukh..... this is the problem - I'm not visiting the route that requires the id...

Comment: Please show the view where you want to call the edit route

Comment: The blade template @Aless55?

Comment: yes, exactly the problem is somewhere in the vlade file I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your code/view file you are trying to do use this `'store.edit.get'` route and you are not passing `id`. You have to do something like this.

```
   {{ route ('store.edit.get', $id) }}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've fixed the problem! I thought the error message meant that I was being sent to the wrong route...